# MYSQL BEST INDEX for 'LIKE' search

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've got a table with approx 100.000.000 phone numbers, VARCHAR15.
What DB Engine and index type would be best(fastest) when using 'like' statements?
Example Where Phone_No like '%1232112'

Cheers!

Rene

Comment: "Example" -- provide the exact queries you want to optimize for. Depending on that - advices may vary. There is no a single strategy that will suit all your requirements.

Comment: "Where Phone_No like '%1232112'" - wildcard prefix is highly unlikely going to use a standard index

Answer (score 6):

> Example Where Phone_No like '%1232112'

For this particular example you might use reversed index. That's it - you create a column with the column's value reversed and maintain it with triggers.

Then you search through it using `LIKE '2112321%'` criteria.